IBus input method for Pinyin showing Cameroon?! Where's China?
I'm using Debian 12. I've installed ibus-pinyin and ibus-libpinyin, then run ibus-setup, and in the Input Method tab, I'm looking for Chinese language or Pinyin input.
When searching "chin", the only result is Achinese (why the A?) which, once clicked, show a list with Indonesian, Malay and Javanese. No Chinese at all.
When searching "piny", there is a Pinyin result which, once clicked, show only two different options for Cameroon (?!).
There's no Zhongwen or 中文 or Hanyu or 汉语.
Where is the Chinese Pinyin?!

"why the A?" – seemingly because it refers to the Aceh people in Indonesia.

The solution I've found was to purge ibus-pinyin (only ibus-libpinyin should be installed), then Chinese and Intelligent-Pinyin appeared. Even though, they must be added (also?) in Gnome Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources (maybe only here suffice).
